# Change space between dialog and screen android

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, dialog

First one is my dialog and I want to make my dialog like reddit but I have no idea how to narrow it.

Here is my code:

```
val dialog = DialogSetting(context!!)
val window = dialog.window
val wlp: WindowManager.LayoutParams = window.attributes

wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
wlp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND
window.attributes = wlp
dialog.show()
```

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom layout...
create a Layout with the desired UI (with margins etc), then inflate the Layout like -

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null, false);
```

then set this view to your AlertDialog like -

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
builder.setView(view);
builder.show();
```

Comment: thanks anyway but i solved it by using dialog bottom sheet

Comment: @KarlEinstein that's a better idea ;)